# Android: Dowloaded files got deleted when the app restarts

Tags: java, android, audio, download, filenotfoundexception

I download audio files from server using

```
          try {

               // URL url = new URL("http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp");
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.2/supplications/"+fileName);
                //URL url = new   URL("http://www.msoftech.com/supplications/android/"+fileName);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();

                Log.v("log_tag", "PATH: " + PATH);
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("log_tag", "Error: " + e);
            }
            Log.v("log_tag", "Check: " +cd2);
```

Here PATH = "/data/data/packagename/sounds/filename

It works fine, audio file downloaded and played successfully, but my problem is when I click the home button and then restart the app means the folder with the downloaded audio was not found, ie, when exit the app means all the downloaded audios were deleted automatically. It throws the exception file not found.

For playing the downloaded file I used the code as below,

```
public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName) throw FileNotFoundException
{
    //set up MediaPlayer 


FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(PATH+"/"+fileName);
            //String command = "chmod 666 " + recordFile.toString(); 
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
               // mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+filename.mp3);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
```

whats the problem with it what I have to do for saving the audio file permenantly.

Comment: where do you save the file? if cache or internal storage, it might get deleted by Android.

Comment: I save the file in path,"/data/data/com.do/sounds/filename.mp3

Comment: xandy is correct. Moreover android suggests to store media files to SD card.

Comment: put logs in public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName) and see what path your are getting.i am afraid you are reading from wrong path..or somehow path is initialized to null

Comment: Is it possible to store the downloaded files in internal memory and I need not the files to be deletd

Comment: @VipulShah the path is correct, since I can play the file after downloading the problem is after getting exit it wont get played file not found

Comment: internal memory only allows about 1 or 2 Mb (not sure), most probably not enough for your mp3 files.

Comment: @xandy is there any options for not allowing the user to delete the file in sd card

Comment: Seems not possible, just like you don't want a file in your computer that you cannot delete, right? But you can put in a hidden folder (starting with `.`), and remember to put .nomedia (to prevent media scanner).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing problem in your code it is a file permission issue. 
When you download file into internal file system under application package a security is assigned to it like "-rw------" this means your file is accessible for the same application only.As android is on Linux based so every file have some permission.

Your file would be there but not accessible to other application like media player etc, so these application throws error like file not found.(you can check though DDMS tool).

Just change the file path to external drive.

Accept the answer if it is helpful.